# SQL REQUEST - Get all conversations with last messages and last date and all users's number

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a structure like this:

```
 id | content         | phone      | date  | conversation_id
----+-------------------------------------------------------
  1 | hello monday    | 0634601825 | 1     | 1
  2 | hello tuesday   | 0768941578 | 2     | 1
  3 | hello wednesday | 0634601825 | 3     | 2
```

I'm trying to make an SQL request to return me one line per conversation_id and the last message, the last date of each one and finally a concat of the numbers.

I don't know why, this request doesn't work:

```
        SELECT m1.conversation_id, MAX(m1.date), (
            SELECT m2.content
            FROM message m2
            WHERE m2.id = m1.id AND m2.date = MAX(m2.date)
        ) as content, (
            SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT m3.phone SEPARATOR ', ')
            FROM message m3
        ) as phones
        FROM message m1
        GROUP BY m1.conversation_id;
```

It returns a list of conversations, with last date, a good concat but not the last message. I know why it's not working, but can't find a solution

Comment: Which db are you using?

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on `group_concat()`

Comment: I founded my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40160275/4745190 Thats a lot all :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT m0.id,m0.content,m0.phone,m0.date,m0.conversation_id
   FROM message AS m0
  LEFT JOIN
        message AS m1 
     ON m0.conversation_id = m1.conversation_id 
    AND m0.content = m1.content
    AND m0.phone = m1.phone
    AND m0.date > m1.date
  WHERE m1.conversation_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I dont understant a lot of functions here ^^ But i've got this error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( PARTITION BY conv_id ORDER BY date DESC ) 
               AS rn
          FROM' at line 5

Comment: Realy thanks to help me, but nope :P  Always the same error.

Comment: Try running the inner query... This should actually work in SQL Server...

Comment: I tryed it on MySQL, the final use is for Sqlite.

Comment: I see.. Mysql seems like doesnt support row_number. Let me write the work around query for u..

Comment: Now your request resturns me the 3 lines :P

Comment: Nope, I need one line per conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id,content,phone,date,conversation_id
from message sd
WHERE sd.date in (SELECT max(date) from message sd1 group BY sd1.conversation_id)
```

The result is your records with id =2 and id = 3

Comment: Thanks for your help but here the phones of the same conversation_id aren't concat :P (Its a little bit hard ^^)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.conv_id, (
    SELECT b.content
    FROM message b
    WHERE a.conv_id = b.conv_id
    ORDER BY b.date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) as content, group_concat(phone SEPARATOR ', ') as phones, (
    SELECT c.date
    FROM message c
    WHERE a.conv_id = c.conv_id
    ORDER BY c.date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) as date
From message a
GROUP BY conv_id
```